# Where did all the stink bugs go?

Tags: bugs

I live near Pittsburgh PA, and I just saw a stink bug, possibly the first one I have seen all year. In the last couple of years they have been a major pest.  Now they seem to be mostly gone.

Where did all the stink bugs go?

Comment: ♪ ♫ Long time passing....

Comment: I was wondering that myself -- I live in Northern Virginia and have seen only a few in both 2019 and in 2018, but nothing like the infestation of several years ago.  My cat did eat one a few weeks ago, and his vomit smelled AWFUL!  I don't remember about 2017.

Comment: There's usually a natural balance so it's not abnromal for huge populations to downsize 'automatically' dus to lack of food/space, but going from a pest to mostly gone in 1 year in my experience usually has a human cause..

Comment: they all came to Europe...

Comment: @Akabelle it is probably all that excitement over brexit...

Comment: New Jersey.  You are welcome to take them back.

Comment: They came to British Columbia last year and thrived here this year :-(

Answer (score 1):

The stink bugs have been heading south and west, first detected in your state, near Allentown, Pennsylvania, back in 1998.  They started showing up 2010 here in Indiana and are still very thick.  They've hit [34 states so far](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_marmorated_stink_bug#In_North_America).

Here's a map showing current [detection areas](http://www.stopbmsb.org/where-is-bmsb/state-by-state/).